# Setting up path ~ in Windows 8.1

Tags: git, path, cmd, windows-8.1, home-directory

I have a problem with git configuration. It starts with some missing directories like .ssh and others that should have been kept inside user home directory (for example C:\Users\Piotr for Piotr's user account).
After using a few commands in cmd I observed that in Windows 8.1 there is no such directory as "~". How can I set up manually? I just want to have "~" linked to my home directory.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a unix thing, but I found a post on superuser that might help with this:

https://superuser.com/questions/168714/is-there-a-shortcut-command-in-windows-command-prompt-to-get-to-the-current-user

Comment: Thanks for your response!

"You can always put a .bat-File somewhere in your %PATH% which does the path changing for you."

How can I do that? And how to code that .bat file to get the path changing?