# How put path changing .bat file inside %PATH%?

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd, environment-variables

I have a problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528668/setting-up-path-in-windows-8-1/19528798) (you can read it for better understanding). I need to write .bat file that change path.

For example:
While sending a command in cmd: `cd ~`
I want to go to %HOMEPATH%. In fact - I just want to replace ~ by %HOMEPATH% in every command which include directories.

How can I achieve it? I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/168729) that I must to put path changing .bat file inside %PATH%. How to do it? And how to code that path changing function in Windows scripting language?

Any advice would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
setx path %path%;path\to\folder\file\is\in

set ~=%homepath%
cd %~%
```

this should work... close enough?

Comment: The main problem is this %~% notation. I need to use ~ without % symbols. However, there is a [solution for my problem](http://superuser.com/a/664078/266034). Thanks for advice!